# R: apply list of functions on list of argument

Tags: r

Say I have several functions in a list and several arguments in another list(They are arranged so that each function calls the right argument):

```
fun_list <- list(f1, f2, f3)
arg_list <- list(a1, a2, a3)
```

Is there a function in R that would apply fun_list on arg_list respectively? More specifically, I want:

```
fun_apply(fun_list, arg_list) == list(f1(a1), f2(a2), f3(a3))
```

Comment: `mapply()` comes to mind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `Map`.  (`Map` is basically `mapply` with a default of `SIMPLIFY = FALSE`.)  For example:

```
fns <- list(mean, median, sum)
values <- list(1:5, 3:7, 5:9)
Map(
  function(fn, value)
  {
    fn(value)
  },
  fns,
  values
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this if you want just the names of the arguments and functions in the list:

```
f1 <- f2 <- f3 <- function(x) x
a1 <- a2 <- a3 <- "14";

fun_list <- list("f1", "f2", "f3")
arg_list <- list("a1", "a2", "a3")

mapply(function(x, y) eval(parse(text=paste(x, "(", y, ")", sep=""))), fun_list, arg_list)
```

If you don't want the names in the list, but the actual arguments and functions:

```
fun_list <- list(f1, f2, f3)
arg_list <- list(a1, a2, a3)

mapply(function(x, y) x(y), fun_list, arg_list)
```

Comment: Is `eval(parse())` really necessary here?

Comment: In case you're using the /names/ of arguments and functions, yes. Otherwise, no. But I wasn't sure exactly what the OP wanted.