# R: apply list of functions on list of argument by name

Tags: r

Someone has solved my question [*applying list of functions on list of argument by order*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25390722/r-apply-list-of-functions-on-list-of-argument), now I have another similar question, how to apply function in the list my name? For example, if I have:

```
f1 <- function(x) {x}
f2 <- function(x) {2*x}
f3 <- function(x) {3*x}
fun_list <- list(good=f1, better=f2, best=f3)
arg_list <- list(better=1, best=2, good=3)
```

I want to get the list of functions called on their respective named parameter, i.e., I want:

```
some_magic_fun(fun_list, arg_list) == list(f1(3), f2(1), f3(2))
```

What would be good way to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**1) mapply**  This does not give a list (2 below does) but it may be what you really want:

```
> mapply(do.call, fun_list, lapply(arg_list[names(fun_list)], list))
good better   best 
   3      2      6
```

**2) Map** This gives a list as the result which is what was asked for.  Its the same as (1) except `mapply` is replaced with `Map`:

```
> Map(do.call, fun_list, lapply(arg_list[names(fun_list)], list))
$good
[1] 3

$better
[1] 2

$best
[1] 6
```

**Revised** based on comments.

Comment: I'm not talking about the class. `good` should get `3`, `better` should get `2`, etc.

Comment: Have revised based on these comments.

Comment: Variation on a theme: `Map(function(x,y) x(y) , fun_list, arg_list[match(names(fun_list),names(arg_list))] )`

Answer (score 10):

As I understand it you want to choose the functions and the arguments from lists not necessarily in order but that have a common set of names:

```
 lapply(names(fun_list), function(n) fun_list[[n]](arg_list[[n]]) )
#----------
[[1]]
[1] 3

[[2]]
[1] 2

[[3]]
[1] 6
```

It wasn't entirely clear if you want the results but that was what I assumed. If you really wanted unevaluated expressions, you will need to clarify.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a possibly magical function:

```
> some_magic_fun <- function(funList, argList){
      m <- match(nmf <- names(funList), names(argList))
      l <- lapply(seq(m), function(i) funList[[i]](m[i]))
      setNames(l, nmf)
  }
> some_magic_fun(fun_list, arg_list)
# $good
# [1] 3
#
# $better
# [1] 2
#
# $best
# [1] 6
```

Keep in mind that this will only work on named lists, and would need to be adjusted for unnamed lists. And also that the last line is optional and I added it in, although your desired result is an unnamed list.